# TextBox and TextAlignment after lost focus when text is longer than TextBox width

Tags: wpf, textbox, dispatcher, alignment, lostfocus

I have the following problem: I have a TextBox in WPF application. When I type in a text that is very long (more characters than what can display in the textbox field)
and than move away from that textbox field (to some other textbox, for example), the text I just typed in, stays right-justified (where I left it).
In other words, I cannot again see the beginning of the text unless I hit Home key or close the screen and open it again.
Can I align the text to the left after I move to the other textbox on the window. I tried with a most probably "fish" solution and it does not work:

```
    private void TextEditControl_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Send, 
                new Action(() => SendKeys.SendWait("{HOME}")));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
```

Comment: +1, on a side note that could fairly easy be turned into an attached behavior for reusability

Answer (score 1):

As per Meleak's note on the Tim Dams' answer, here's how you do it as an attached behavior:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public static class TextBoxBehavior
{
    public static bool GetHomeOnLostFocus(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(HomeOnLostFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHomeOnLostFocus(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HomeOnLostFocusProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HomeOnLostFocus.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HomeOnLostFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "HomeOnLostFocus", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(TextBoxBehavior), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnHomeOnLostFocusChanged));

    public static void OnHomeOnLostFocusChanged(
        DependencyObject d, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Type checking and casting of parameters
        bool oldVal = (bool)e.OldValue;
        bool newVal = (bool)e.NewValue;
        TextBox textBox = d as TextBox;

        // Argument value tests
        if (textBox == null) return;
        if (oldVal == newVal) return;

        // If HomeOnLostFocus then add event handler, otherwise, remove it.
        if (newVal)
            textBox.LostFocus += TextBox_LostFocus;
        else
            textBox.LostFocus -= TextBox_LostFocus;
    }

    static void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        textBox.SelectionStart = 0;
    }
}
```

Need references to `PresentationCore`, `PresentationFramework`, `System.Xaml` and `WindowsBase` assemblies.

Here's the usage example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:tbb="clr-namespace:TextBoxBehavior;assembly=TextBoxBehavior"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Width="200"/>
        <TextBox tbb:TextBoxBehavior.HomeOnLostFocus="true" Width="200"/>
        <Button Content="Dummy" Width="200"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Note the `xmlns:tbb` attribute and its usage on the 2nd `TextBox`.